# Swift: Backendless sorting relationship objects

Tags: ios, swift, backendless

I have this Backendless tables: `Posts` and `Comments`

Posts has a column `comments` which is has a one-to-many relationship to Comments table.

I'm try to get the `comments` in a latestOrder first behavior.

Currently, I have this query:

```
  let query = BackendlessDataQuery()
  let queryOptions = QueryOptions()
  queryOptions.pageSize = size
  queryOptions.related = ["comments", "comments.user", "user", "media"]
  query.queryOptions = queryOptions
  // Used PostObject since it is already mapped using `mapTableToClass`
  backendlessInstance.persistenceService.of(PostObject.ofClass()).find(
    query,
    response: { backendlessPostsList in
      let backendlessPostsListOfOffset = backendlessPostsList.getPage(offset)
      guard let postObjects = backendlessPostsListOfOffset.getCurrentPage() as? [PostObject] else {
        reject(BackendlessError.InvalidTypeForObject(name: "Post"))
        return
      }
      return postObjects
    },
    error: { fault in
      // TODO Find a way to convert a Fault to ErrorType
      print("Server reported an error (1): \(fault)")
    }
  )
```

What I'm doing currently to sort Post.comments in the view model is reversing it. `Post.comments.reverse()`.

Is there a way to explicitly sort the `comments` in Backendless level?

Comment: You can set a sort attribute on the query options, I'm not exactly sure what you're asking...

Comment: @Wain I just want to sort comments in latestFirst order without compromising the order of PostObjects.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have options when using `related`, and you should really just use it for to-one relationships, not to-many because of this. It would work ok if you have a one-to-few relationship.

So, you should make a separate request for the comments so you can specify a specific page size and sort order. Note that when you specify the variable to sort by (`created`) you can also add `asc` or `desc` to specify the direction of the sort (so `created desc`).

Comment: I see. Thanks for the advise Wain! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the sort function.

```
let sortedComments = Post.comments.sort { $0.date > $1.date }
```

Of corse your comments will need a published date field for this to work.